# Video buffering in chromedriver

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a chromedriver application that visits a website and watches a video. Unfortunatly, the video doesn't play completelty smoothly as it would in a normal browser, but instead it plays for around 4 seconds, then freezes for a bit, and then repeats. Its always 4 seconds. Is this some sort of buffer setting? Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @gunr2171 the code is just initating the chromedriver and using navigate.goToUrl and that's it. I figured it was irrelevant because of it's simplicity.